# How to add editable View components to a layout in Android?

Tags: android, layout, addition

So, what I'd like is: defining a component, which includes TextView-s and an ImageView. This is an item, which I'd like to add to a (for example Linear) layout, so I can display all the custom items, I added one after the other.
The point is, that these items have to be editable, because a database query result will define their text content and the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom component should be a `ViewGroup` itself. You can add any number of `TextView`s and `ImageView`s to it, and access them by their ID.

```
MyCustomViewGroup component = (MyCustomViewGroup)linearLayout.findViewById(...);
TextView textView1 = (TextView)component.findViewById(...);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)component.findViewById(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the [XML approach for defining your component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). For instance, you can define your component as a LinearLayout, then add all the elements (TextViews, ImageViews) you need to that layout. 
As for the "editable" part, just provide your elements with an id property 
`android:id="@+id/my_view"`; that way you may obtain them through a  `findViewById(R.id.my_view)` call. 
You cast the results to whatever View implementation you are expecting, then change it's text/content/image with the interpreted results from your query.